# how to import an xy plot in png format, and sample it

Tags: r, import, plot, png, sample

I have an xy plot (time v.s synthetic index price) in png format. Because I cannot find the raw data with which I used to generate this plot. I wanna sample this plot and get some estimation.

Unfortunately, I've never deal with importing image files and processing the data, would you please give me some hints? which package, function, or any useful suggestion?

> basic info:
>
> file format: png
>
> img background: white
>
> line color: black

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Can you post an example image?

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955077/image-analysis-in-r) and links therein could be a start.

Comment: it's really a simple one, take this as an example: http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Training/Exercises/Images/xy2_ex01.png
but mine is even simpler, no x/y axis and border, just the xy curve itself.

Comment: Here is [another similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133040/finding-coordinate-of-sketch-image-eg-scanned-as-photo-format-in-r-or-other-s/14142962).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you not try to do this in `R`.  There are several good tools for extracting data from a plot.  My favorites are datathief   http://www.datathief.org/    and engauge  http://digitizer.sourceforge.net/.  Run those, then import the data (ascii text) they generate into `R`